# SubnetUtils isInRange Method Return True - False Positive Issue

Tags: java, networking, subnet

I create a method that have this code script :

```
SubnetUtils utils = new SubnetUtils("15.0.0.0/8");
        if (utils.getInfo().isInRange("170.2.1.1"))
        {
            // Do some code
        }
```

the if statement returns true ! But the single ip isn't in range.

What am I doing wrong? Is there's another way to check if single ip in range?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SubnetUtils subnetUtils = new SubnetUtils("cidrRange");
**subnetUtils.setInclusiveHostCount(true);**
boolean withinRange = subnetUtils.getInfo().isInRange("ipAddress");
```

Setting the inclusiveHostCount to true returns the low dotted ip address instead of 0 for CIDR/31 and CIDR/32.

Reference : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.SubnetInfo.html#isInRange-java.lang.String-

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-and-link-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answer given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Comment: Noted and addressed

Answer (score 0):

It's showing the correct result on ,y system. See the following image:

I also printed the min & max range:

```
System.out.println("lower address: " + utils.getInfo().getLowAddress());
System.out.println("higher address: " + utils.getInfo().getHighAddress());
```

I am using version 3.3 for SubnetUtils lib

[image]

Comment: Also with version 3.3 it doesn't work .
But for "16.1.1.1" single ip it works, It returns false - that the ip isn't in range !

Comment: I didn't understand, did it work for you or not? It worked on my system and I attached the screenshot for the same.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I created a method for my own that can check IPv4 and IPv6